# What is the etymology of "hautboys"?

Tags: etymology

Strangely, Etymonline.com doesn't give an [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=hautboys&searchmode=none).

I looked up [Dictionary.com,](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hautboy) and came up with:

> 1565–75;  < Middle French hautbois,  equivalent to haut  high ( see haughty) + bois  wood ( see bush1 )

So, how did this word "high wood" come to mean [oboe?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hautboy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explained on the [oboe entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oboe)

> [C18: via Italian oboe,  phonetic
>   approximation to French haut bois, 
>   literally: high wood (referring to its
>   pitch)]

and [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=oboe)

> oboe 
>       1724, from It. oboe, from M.Fr. hautbois (itself borrowed in English
>   16c. as hautboy), from haut "high,
>   loud, high-pitched" + bois "wood" (see
>   bush). So called because it had the
>   highest register among woodwind
>   instruments.

Comment: What @JoseK has not spelled out is that the French "bois", which is now pronounced "bwa", went through stages "bwi" and "bwe". "Haut" is still pronounced "o". So when "haut bois" was borrowed into Italian it was presumably "o bwe".